# how to use a non static variable of a class ( let A) in another class ( let B). Here , cannot create a instance of A in B

Tags: java, class, variables, static, instance

I want to use a variable of one class (let it be A) in another class (let it be B), but I cannot create an instance for the first class A in class B and should not use static keyword in class A

Comment: "statis variable has to be obtained from instance methods", this makes no sense. anyway, either your variable is static, and you can access it directly, or it isn't, and you can't

Answer (score 1):

If the variable is not static, then it doesn't exist without an instance. You may be misunderstanding how OO variables are meant to work.

Think of a class called Person.

If you want a variable that is the same for everyone like "species" then you want a static variable.

```
static final String species = "Homo sapiens";
```

Otherwise, if you want something that varies from person to person, then you need a person to exist to get the answer. Otherwise it's like asking "What colour are a person's eyes?" You need to know which person you're talking about to know the answer.

So, if you're trying to call a variable that is constant among all objects of your class then you can make it static. That's what static is there for.
Otherwise, you need to reference an instance.